# Mono: Webservice prepending UTF-8 BOM in XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, mono

I took a project done in Visual Studio 2008 an rebuilt it on Linux with Monodevelop 2.4.2 and mono 2.10.2.

The output SOAP generated by the mono version is including an UTF-8 BOM (ef bb bf) header that can't be handled by the server, generating the exception below:

```
"Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.sun.xml.stream.XMLStreamException2: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog."
```

How can I instruct the mono autogenerated webservice client to not include this BOM?

Wireshark sniff:

```
000000B5  ef bb bf 3c 3f 78 6d 6c  20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e ...<?xml  version
000000C5  3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65  6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d ="1.0" e ncoding=
000000D5  22 75 74 66 2d 38 22 3f  3e 3c 73 3a 45 6e 76 65 "utf-8"? ><s:Enve
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use basicHttpBinding for client creation, you should set Encoding without BOM

```
ClientBaseImp client = new ClientBaseImp();
((BasicHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding).TextEncoding 
        = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Last line `new UTF8Encoding(false)` removes BOM.

Comment: You should add a bit of explanation

Comment: You should use explicit cast to `BasicHttpBinding` instead of `as` operator. If something goes wrong you'll end up with `ObjectNullReference` exception, while explicit casting will give you a clue that you cannot cast to `BasicHttpBinding`. So, use `((BasicHttpBinding)client.Endpoint.Binding).TextEncoding`.